# How can I get the current user in azure AAD, with ADAL/OpenId?

Tags: c#, azure, adal

I have the following code to get the context token.

```
public class UserProfileController : Controller
    {
        private static string azureAdGraphApiEndPoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AzureAdGraphApiEndPoint"];
        private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
        private static string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppKey"];

        public async Task<ActionResult> GetPropertiesForUser()
        {
            Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(azureAdGraphApiEndPoint);
            var token = await GetAppTokenAsync();

            ActiveDirectoryClient adClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(
             serviceRoot,
             async () => await GetAppTokenAsync());
            string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

            Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Application app = (Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Application)adClient.Applications.Where(
                a => a.AppId == clientId).ExecuteSingleAsync().Result;
            if (app == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Unable to get a reference to application in Azure AD.");
            }

            string requestUrl = string.Format("https://graph.windows.net/mysaasapp.onmicrosoft.com/users/{0}?api-version=1.5", token);

            HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
            hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                "Bearer", token);

            HttpResponseMessage hrm = await hc.GetAsync(new Uri(requestUrl));

            if (hrm.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string jsonresult = await hrm.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return View("TestRestCall", new SuccessViewModel
                {
                    Name = "The Title",
                    Message = "The message",
                    JSON = jsonresult.ToJson()
                });
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        private static async Task<string> GetAppTokenAsync()
        {
            string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
            string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppKey"];
            string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
            string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
            string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];
            string azureAdGraphApiEndPoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AzureAdGraphApiEndPoint"];
            // This is the resource ID of the AAD Graph API.  We'll need this to request a token to call the Graph API.
            string graphResourceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:GraphResourceId"];

            string Authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);

            // Instantiate an AuthenticationContext for my directory (see authString above).
            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, false);

            // Create a ClientCredential that will be used for authentication.
            // This is where the Client ID and Key/Secret from the Azure Management Portal is used.
            ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);

            // Acquire an access token from Azure AD to access the Azure AD Graph (the resource)
            // using the Client ID and Key/Secret as credentials.
            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId, clientCred);

            // Return the access token.
            return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
        }
```

However I need to replace the token with the current user email, but havent found how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, forgive me if I've misunderstood the problem.

If you want to get the user's email from Claims, I think that can be somewhat different depending on your tenant. For me, I can find my email i Claims under both "upn" and "unique name".

So as an example;

```
string email= ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn) != null ? ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn).Value : ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value;
```

This would give me my email, or null.

In my case, if I use, as you do, ""http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier"", that returns a GUID uniquely identifying me in my tenants Active Directory.

Have you inspected your Claims to see what is in there?

Comment: What if you want to get some other part of the User Profile from Azure AD that is NOT in the set of claims.  I think we need to make another authorized require to graph to get additional details like title or department